# Edit Text calculo automatico - Android - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpIfZ.png)sou iniciante na programação andoid apesar de saber desenvolver layouts estou com algumas dificuldades em colocar a logica de programação em alguns casos. Desde ja agradeço pessoal.

Tenho : EditText(Number) , TextView1 , Button , TextView2.

Preciso fazer com que o numero que o usuario coloque no EditeText seja automaticamente multiplicado por 2.68 (float) e o resultado da multiplicação saia na Textview

Segundo é que o resultado dessa multiplicação ao apertar o botão seja multiplicado por 33.00 e o resultado saia na TextView2

class Item : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_item)

```
    val editTextNumber: EditText= findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber)
    val textView2: TextView =findViewById(R.id.textView2)
    val button: ImageButton= findViewById(R.id.imageButton3)
    val txtResult: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView4)



    

    val resultado1 = editTextNumber.text.toString().toFloat()
    val resultado2 = textView2.text.toString().toFloat()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode fazer da seguinte forma.

1 - Adicione um listener no Edittext que voce quer que o calculo seja automatico e adicione a logica no metodo afterTextChanged.

```
editTextNumber.addTextChangedListener( object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        // Esse metodo e chamado a cada vez que o usuario altera o valor do EditText
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            // Transformo o texto do EditText para numero usando o Integer.parse
            // Multiplico esse numero por 2.68
            // Transformo ele em texto e coloco o resultado no TextView
           textView2.text = (Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber.text.toString()) * 2.68).toString()
        }

    })
```

2 - Adicione a funcao de click no Button

```
// Adicionei o evento de click no botao
button.setOnClickListener {
    // Aqui eu transformo o texto em numero, faco o calculo com o resultado que esta no primeiro TextView multiplicado por 33 e coloco no segundo TextView
    txtResult.text = Integer.parseInt(textView2.text) * 33
}
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema!